# Degree and Family of Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{P}^{n_2}$. For each point $p\in\mathbb{P}^{n_2}$, we consider the closed subscheme $X_p$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}$. We use the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{P}^{n_2}\to \mathbb{P}^{N}$ with $N=(n_1-1)(n_2-1)+1$ to define the number $\deg X$.

**Question 1:** Does there exist a real $M$ such that for all $p\in\mathbb{P}^{n_2}$, we have $\deg(X_p)\leq M$ ?

**Question 2:** Does there exist a function $f$ independent of $X$ such that for all $p\in\mathbb{P}^{n_2}$, we have $\deg(X_p)\leq f(\deg(X),\dim(X))$ ?

Comment: Is the map $X$ to ${\mathcal P}^{n_1}$ flat over its image, perchance? Otherwise I don't know what its dimension will be, so $\deg$ becomes problematic to think about. Relatedly, you probably want $X$ irreducible, else you can often stick some junk in one of the $X_p$, giving it large degree while not changing $\deg(X),\dim(X)$.

Comment: Thank you. Do we know if $p\mapsto \deg(X_p)$ is just bounded ?

Comment: Since each $X_p$ is the intersection of $X$ with the subvariety $\mathbb{P}^{n_1} \times p \subset \mathbb{P}^N$, can't you bound the degree of $X_p$ by a suitable product?